# Scipy.io.mmread Throws Value Error in Streamlit Heroku App

Tags: heroku, scipy, streamlit

I have been trying to read a scipy matrix file in my streamlit app.
The app runs on local machine without any errors in app or console.
While deployed on Heroku it raises `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)`
on the line `co_occurrence_matrix = scipy.io.mmread("./database/matrix.mtx")`.

I've crosschecked the following points, and not sure where to look for the problem.

- Matrix is created with

```
smatrix =  scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(matrix)
scipy.isspmatrix(smatrix) #-> returns True
scipy.io.mmwrite("./database/matrix.mtx\",smatrix)
```

- All library versions including python itself are identical between the two apps. Both checked on consoles with `pip list`. And requirements file is created with pip freeze.
- Files are synchronized on git, `git status` returns 'up to date. Heroku uses the file on git, the local app runs on the synchronized file.
- If it makes any difference, the .mtx file is uploaded via git lfs.
- Heroku deploys the app successfully, yet inside the streamlit app, it gives the error.

Full Error:

> ```
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
>     exec(code, module.__dict__)File "/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
>     from gorsellestirme_util import set_bg, Plotter, matrix, word_list, main_dfFile "/app/gorsellestirme_util.py", line 30, in <module>
>     matrix, word_list, main_df = matrix_reader()File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 625, in wrapped_func
>     return get_or_create_cached_value()File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 609, in get_or_create_cached_value
>     return_value = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)File "/app/gorsellestirme_util.py", line 12, in matrix_reader
>     co_occurrence_matrix = mmread("./database/matrix.mtx")File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/io/_mmio.py", line 77, in mmread
>     return MMFile().read(source)File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/io/_mmio.py", line 438, in read
>     self._parse_header(stream)File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/io/_mmio.py", line 502, in _parse_header
>     self.__class__.info(stream)File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/io/_mmio.py", line 234, in info
>     mmid, matrix, format, field, symmetry = \
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the source of the problem: It is clearly stated in the Heroku docs that Heroku does not support git-lfs files. I've missed that point.

As a workaround, there are multiple build packs in [Heroku elements](https://elements.heroku.com/search?q=git%20lfs). FYI, those buildpacks are also limited with Heroku's 500Mb filesize cap. And security has to be considered as an issue as those buildpacks require third-party access to your git.

Comment: Littlebit irrelevant solution: [Render](https://render.com) offers LFS support as default. Yet free plan offers 512 MB memory like Heroku however it could be raised in paid options.